# How to add sliding menu in android using ADT

Tags: android

I am trying to add Sliding menu's in android app, but I didn't understand from where to add this. Most of today's apps have this. Please suggest how do I start and add Sliding menu...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is how to make a navigation drawer. You should take a look at this documentation https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html.

Moreover, at Google I/O, Google released the "Android design library" with some cool enhancements to build a navigation drawer. You can find a blog post about it here http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

You can also check this Github for an example of how to implement it : https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare